# datatables with ajax response

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, datatables, laravel-blade

**How to use java script variable inside blade syntax. (getting error Use of undefined constant buttonID)**

The below is the code :

```
  var t = $("#datatable").DataTable({
        "order": [[ 1, 'asc' ]],
        "ajax": "questions1/get-data",
        "deferRender": true,
        "processing": true,
        sAjaxDataProp: "",
        "columns": [
            { "data": "id" },
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "description" },
            { "data": "answers.[, ].name" },
            { "data": "campaigns.[, ].name" },
            { "data": "label" },
            {
                sortable: false,
                "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
                    var buttonID = full.id;
                    return '@can('view', $question)<a href="{{ url('/admin/survey-details/questions/' + buttonID ) }}" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" title="View Question"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" aria-hidden="true"/></a>@endcan
                        @can('update', $question)<a href="{{ url('/admin/survey-details/questions/12/edit') }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" title="Edit Question"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"/></a>@endcan';
                }
            }

        ],

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the code below:

```js
"render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
   var buttonID = full.id;

   @can('view', $question)
   return '<a href="{{ url('/admin/survey-details/questions') }}/' + encodeURI(buttonID) + '" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" title="View Question"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" aria-hidden="true"/></a>';
   @endcan

   @can('update', $question)
   return '<a href="{{ url('/admin/survey-details/questions/12/edit') }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" title="Edit Question"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"/></a>';
   @endcan
}
```